# Box-Muller: Generate i.i.d Standard Normal from 1 Chi-squared and 1 Unit Uniform RV

Tags: sampling, random-generation

Situation: I am given one chi-square RV and one unit uniform random RV.

Question: How can I use the Box-Muller method to generate i.i.d. standard normal random samples using only these two RVs, assuming I must use both RVs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can generate a standard normal given two uniform random variables, without a chi-squared variable. Given uniform unit random samples ($U_1$ and $U_2$), Box-Mueller can be used to generate two i.i.d. standard normals $Z_0$ and $Z_1$ using the following formulas:

$ Z_0 = \sqrt{-2\cdot ln(U_1)} \cdot cos(2\pi U_2) $

$ Z_1 = \sqrt{-2\cdot ln(U_1)} \cdot sin(2\pi U_2) $

Often, "$R^2$" is defined as

$ R^2 = -2\cdot ln(U_1)$,

According to Wikipedia,

> **Because $R^2$ is the square of the norm of the standard bivariate normal variable $(X, Y)$, it has the chi-squared distribution with two degrees of freedom.** In the special case of two degrees of freedom, the chi-squared distribution coincides with the exponential distribution, and the equation for $R^2$ above is a simple way of generating the required exponential variate.

So, if you are given a variable $A$ with a chi-squared distribution and another variable $B$ with a uniform unit distribution, you can generate a standard normal ($X$) using the following:

$ X = \sqrt{A} \cdot cos(2 \pi B)$

Comment: I see, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:** Checking @ERT's method (+1), with sample of $n=5000.$
Obvious procedures seem to be on target.

```
set.seed(402)
a = rchisq(5000, 2)
b = runif(5000)
x = sqrt(a)*cos(1*pi*b)

summary(x); sd(x)
      Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
 -3.813066 -0.663294  0.016787  0.003001  0.663570  3.495904 
[1] 0.9923197  # sample SD
```

Passes Shapiro-Wilk and Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests.

```
shapiro.test(x)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  x
W = 0.99962, p-value = 0.473

ks.test(x, pnorm)

        One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x
D = 0.0085232, p-value = 0.8607
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Normal probability plot is suitably 'linear' and histogram is a reasonable
fit to standard normal density.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 qqnorm(x); qqline(x, col="green")
 hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
  curve(dnorm(x), add=T, lwd=2, col="orange")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

*Note:* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform)
on Box-Muller.

Comment: OP must be quite happy, you completed part (b) of their assignment for them!